# How to fix my system freezing every time I launch a video after installing mpv?

Tags: video, mpv-media-player

Since installing mpv, every time I launch a video, my system completely freezes, and I have to do a hard shutdown. Even when trying to use another media player (SMPlayer with `mpv` as its backend or VLC as already mentioned), the same thing happens. I'm new to Linux and am trying it out on an external drive using Kubuntu.

I installed it following the instructions on its [website](https://mpv.io/installation/), which says to follow the link [Ubuntu (PPA)](https://launchpad.net/%7Emc3man/+archive/ubuntu/mpv-tests), which says to install [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html), and then follow the instructions on that page to add the PPA and install:

```bash
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/mpv-tests
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install mpv
```

Computer specs:

```bash
OS: Kubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64 
Host: HP Pavilion dv7 Notebook PC Rev 1 
Kernel: 5.8.0-59-generic
Resolution: 1600x900
CPU: Intel Core 2 Quad Q9000 (4) @ 2.001GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI Mobility Radeon HD 4650/5165 
Memory: 5912MiB
```

Because @heynnema asked:

```bash
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          5.8Gi       2.1Gi       1.9Gi        27Mi       1.8Gi       3.4Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

Comment: @CactusCities MPV may not be the fix, as you mentioned that other video players had the same problem. Please see my answer below. If you still have a problem, and my answer helps to resolve it, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for your responses. My other video players began working again after reinstalling mpv. It seems something happened with the install that messed things up, as I didn't have the issue before the install. However, I'm sure having a larger swapfile will be helpful, so I followed the instructions of your answer. and my swapfile is now 4GB. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by uninstalling and reinstalling mpv.

```
sudo apt remove mpv
sudo apt install mpv
```

Edit: Actually fixed by uninstalling SMPlayer. SMPlayer doesn't support mpv version 0.33 yet. Changing SMPlayer to use MPlayer would also work.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2G /swapfile is too small. You probably have a freezing or crashing problem.

Let's increase the /swapfile from 2G to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 6G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```

**Update #1:**

Uninstalling and reinstalling the MPV application resolved the problem. /swapfile was also changed from 2G to 4G.

Answer (score -1):

System "freezes" are often caused by running too many, too large programs and running out of available memory. Use `free` to see if you have swap space, read `man mkswap swapon fstab` to create some. Swap space must be contiguous. use `mkswap` or `fallocate`, not `dd`. Traditionally, swap space of 1.5 × RAM has been recommended,  but YMMV. If you don't plan to hibernate your system, you can have less than 1.0 × RAM.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'll save this info for later use. Didn't see it as I was editing my post.